# Зачем нужен return

Tags: javascript, функции

Может кто-нибудь знает, почему следующий код js выводит "1"? Как он работает? Так как я не понимаю, для чего там написан `return;`, и функция переопределяет `а` или нет

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
  a = 10;
  return;
  function a() {}
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что используется не Русский язык

Comment: @Vayok, здесь показана особенность парсера JS: если переменная использована как глобальная (т.е. без var), но при этом где-то дальше в коде в текущем контексте есть объявление такой же переменной, то переменная автоматически становится локальной. У вас объявляется функция `a` внутри функции `b`, поэтому `a = 10` равносильно `var a = 10;`, т.е. никаким образом эта строчка не влияет на переменную `a` за пределами функции

Comment: @BOPOH спасибо за коммент. если честно я код понял но слова нет.  Но решаю не только я. Если вопрос исправит автор, конечно уберу голос на закрытие

Comment: `return` в данном случае ни на что не влияет, так как после него нет исполняемых операций, а определение функции `а` переносится парсером в начало функции `b`

Comment: Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/foundation/structure#oblast-vidimosti): *Обратите внимание, в javascript все директивы var срабатывают при входе в функцию, неважно где они находятся.* Функция, по сути, та же самая переменная

Comment: @BOPOH - Но не присваивание значений.

Comment: @Igor, не понял? Локальные переменные (или те же функции) создаются при входе в функцию, а значит все присваивания "вроде-как-глобальных-переменных" выполняются на самом деле уже на локальных переменных

Comment: @BOPOH - Пардон, я имел в виду, что для `var а = 123;` `var a;` переносится в начало функции, а `а = 123;` остается там где было.

Comment: @Igor, а, ну да, я про это и писал

Comment: Я могу писать по руски но не грамотно, поскольку я украинец)

Comment: @Vasyok: Спробуйте спитати щось українською на англомовній сторінці stackoverflow.com. Буду дуже здивований, якщо ваше запитання не буде закрито впродовж 3 хвилин, ще й нахапаєте мінусів.

Comment: Почему нельзя бить проще?

Comment: Спасибо всем за хорошие доступние ответи)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что объявление функции всплывает.

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
  function a() {}
  a = 10;
  return;
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

После этого ты берёшь имя `a`, которое обозначает функцию, и используешь в качестве переменной, в которую помещаешь 10. Фактически, ссылка на функцию теряется, но ты её нигде и не используешь. Выходит нечто такое:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
  var a = function a() {}
  a = 10;
  return;
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

Ну и естественно, функция меняла внутреннюю переменную, а внешняя как была равна 1, так и осталась.

А `return` тут и не при чём вовсе.

Comment: 2 ответа нравятса но не знаю куда галочку поставить, што делать?))

Comment: @Vasyok, выбирать. Кстати, мой был дан раньше.

Comment: @Qwertiy Хитрый способ чтобы приняли твой ответ :)

Answer (score 13):

В данном примере

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
  a = 10;
  return;
  function a() {}
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

предложение `return` используется преднамеренно, чтобы запутать того, кто будет пытаться понять или отвечать на вопрос, как работает код. То есть предложение `return` помещено перед определением функции с именем `a`, дабы у смотрящего этот код создалось впечатление, что это определение функции будет просто проигнорировано и никак не повлияет на выполнение функции `b` и на коллизию имени `a` для глобальной переменной и переменной, используемой в объявлении функции.

В таких языках программирования, как, например, C++, где есть область видимости переменной, начинающаяся с момента ее объявления, это было бы верно.

Однако в `JavaScript` действуют другие правила видимости переменных. Когда функция становится активной, то сначала парсер просматривает все объявления переменных в данной функции и делает областью их видимости всю функцию. Это можно представить следующим образом

```
function b() {
  function a() {}
  a = 10;
  return;
}
```

То есть объявление функции с именем `a` как будто бы помещается в самое начало функции `b`. Тем самым глобальная переменная `a` скрывается, а в функции происходит обращение к локальной переменной с тем же именем `a`.

Сначала эта переменная объявляется как ссылка на функцию, а затем ей присваивается значение 10, так как `JavaScript` не типизированный язык, а переменные использует для хранения любых значений.

Поэтому присвоение

```
  a = 10;
```

никак не влияет на глобальную переменную `a`, которой было присвоено значение `1`

```
var a = 1;
```

Поэтому предложение

```
console.log(a);
```

выведет в консоль это значение глобальной переменной.

Кстати сказать, после предложения

```
  a = 10;
```

вы уже не можете обратиться к функции с именем `a`, даже если убрать предложение с `return`, так как ссылка на функцию тем самым утеряна. То есть вы не можете написать, например

```
function b() {
  a = 10;
  function a() {}
  a();
}
```