# Что значит return в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, функции, return

При изучении JavaScript, я дошел до return. Не понимал для чего это надо. Сначала пробовал как-нибудь "допонять", далее поискать в гугле объяснения, но слишком уж было все замудренно сказано. Что значит возвратить результат? Для чего нужен return? И куча разных других вопросов ко всему этому. Надеюсь, что объясните все своими словами и заранее спасибо

Comment: то есть вы прочитали кучу объяснений и не поняли? отдохните денек другой от учебы и приступите снова

Comment: Все равно будет непонятно...

Comment: @YorkIsMine,  плохой настрой))) Все получится и все поймете, возможно действительно нужно передохнуть и вновь почитать и запустить несколько примеров! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846086/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-return-%D0%B2-javascript

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466154/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-return

Comment: возможно и так. В любом случае вам тоже спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
//функция calculate принимает на вход два параметра: a, b
//выполняет работу (складывает эти два числа) и результат возвращает (для этого служит оператор return)
//после return указывается что именно надо возвратить
//если не нравится слово возвращает, можешь заменить его словом 'выдает'
function calculate(a, b) {
  x = a + b;
  return x;
}

//так как функция возвращает результат, то его можно записать в переменную number
//мы передаем в функцию calculate два числа: 2 и 3
//она их складывает и возвращает(выдает) результат 5
//этот результат записывается в переменную number
var number = calculate(2, 3);

//теперь в консоли мы можем посмотреть чему равна переменная number
console.log(number);
```

Comment: вот как...спасибо тебе большое!)

Comment: @YorkIsMine можешь принять ответ, раз помог)

Answer (score 3):

У функции есть вход и выход, на входе функция получает аргументы, на выходе выдаёт результат. Вот return как раз означает выход из функции и выдача результата.

Comment: спасибо. Кажется, начинаю все понимать